# LiveSuit problems

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rom-flashing

I have formatted my Chinese tablet PC from 'LiveSuit' software.

Now my tablet PC is showing blank screen.

Please tell me how can I re-install the operating system on my tablet?

*Old operating system is ICS.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a ROM image that has been built for your specific tablet. If you want to reinstall the OS you had before, you need to obtain the same ROM image the manufacturer used. You might be able to get this from the manufacturer. (But if you want this, why would you wipe the ROM?)

Alternatively, you could install a [custom-rom](/questions/tagged/custom-rom). These can be found on various web fora such as [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com) by searching for the model of your tablet. You may be able to get one for a different Android version, but only if someone has built an image for the model you have.

Once you have the ROM image, simply use LiveSuit again to flash it to the device.